# IllegalArgumentException exception but not find the source file

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

This exception is found only in the release version. I've tested several devices but not getting on my phone. Also getting this exception only in the release version.

Case history: 
I've used Android AutoCompleteTextView and after prepare data, I've forced `showDropdown();` method for show forcefully.

Following devices were affected.

> Galaxy J2 Galaxy J5(2016)  Galaxy J5  Primo_RM3 (Primo_RM3)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked (WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout (WindowManagerGlobal.java:308)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout (WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
  at android.widget.PopupWindow.update (PopupWindow.java:1579)
  at android.widget.PopupWindow.update (PopupWindow.java:1659)
  at android.widget.PopupWindow.update (PopupWindow.java:1612)
  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show (ListPopupWindow.java:609)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown (AutoCompleteTextView.java:1105)
  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setFrame (AutoCompleteTextView.java:1051)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15675)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1077)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1077)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)
  at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.onLayout (SourceFile:415)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onLayout (SourceFile:229)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.c (SourceFile:1167)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a (SourceFile:852)
  at android.support.design.widget.x.b (SourceFile:63)
  at android.support.design.widget.x.a (SourceFile:42)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.a (SourceFile:1055)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.a (SourceFile:772)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (SourceFile:870)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:15679)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5039)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2098)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:773)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:586)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:556)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:759)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:901)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: it happen when you activity is already destroy and you try to open a popup or dialog

Comment: May be you are right, but I'm not getting any source file reference. How may I distinguish that?

Comment: as you mention,you are calling  showDropdown() method after data is prepared ,may it cause from there,add you code for showDropdown()

Comment: Yes. In the last build, I've added exception handling around showDropDown();. Still getting an exception. I've just suspected that method because actually, i don't know where the exception occurring.  If you want I can put code here.

Comment: have you used PopupWindow ?because it clearly mention in Log issue with PopupWindow

Comment: add the code,Error is because of showDropdown() with AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Please check this 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd43e02dc36c60657ac407fe806a4a93#file-gistfile1-txt